# Проблема с масштабом View в IOS 6.0 Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

Впервые делаю апп под IOS 6.0

- Deployment target - 6.0
- scheme - iPhone 6.0 Simulator
- в симуляторе выставлено устройство - iPhone retina 4-inch, версия 6.0
- в Interface Builder View тоже длинные.

Но на симуляторе все равно приложение отображается обрезанным как будто это приложение под предыдущие оси. Что еще нужно выставить, чтобы в симуляторе увидеть растянутое на весь экран пятого айфона приложение?

Comment: Делал клин проекту в икскоде и убивал настройки симулятора - не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось просто - когда стартовал проект поубивал дефолтные сплешскрины. 568@2x является флагом совместимости с новым экраном в iOS 6